# How to run a function when the mouse is held down with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, mousemove

I have a jquery function that uses the canvas to create lines much like you can do with Paint. The function works by making circles when the mouse is moved over the canvas. I would like to alter this function to run only when the mouse is moved over the canvas AND the user holds down the mouse. Here is the function:

```
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(event) {
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.fillStyle = "fuchsia";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(event.pageX, event.pageY, 6, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fill();
});
```

Is there an at least relatively straight-forward way of achieving this? I have no idea how to even start. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to catch the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to set/unset a `mouse_is_down` flag, and use that in your `mousemove` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute code if `event.which == 1`. This verifies the pressing of left button (holding down the mouse).

For more [`MouseEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which).

```js
$("#canvas").on('mousemove',function(event) {
  if(event.which == 1){
    var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.fillStyle = "fuchsia";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(event.pageX, event.pageY, 6, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
  }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: It would also be good if you explained or linked what `event.which` means in this context

Comment: This is a great answer, exactly what I was looking for. However, I do not understand event.which. Could you explain?

Comment: @MichaelAlexander, `event.which` is a property that indicates which button was pressed on the mouse to trigger the event. I have provided a link in the answer. Please visit that for details.